# Minimal positive integer divisible by n

Tags: c, algorithm, math

For the given number n find the minimal positive integer divisible by n, with the sum of digits equal to n.

I have searched a lot and also got some answer to this question but those are not easy to understand for me. I'm a new programmer and like to code in C programming language. That's why I will be happy if anyone help me to find the solution of this problem in C. 
How ever I've tried and my code isn't working for large input of n. such that n=999.
My code goes here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long long int summingDigit(long long int dividend);

int main()
{
    long long int n, dividend, add, ans;
    int i, test, c;
    scanf("%d", &test);
    for(c=1; c<=test; c++) {
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    for(i=1; ; i++) {
        dividend = n*i;
        add = summingDigit(dividend);
        if(add==n) {
            ans=dividend;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%lld\n", dividend);
    }
    return 0;
    }


long long int summingDigit(long long int dividend)
{
    long long int sum=0, rem;
    while(dividend!=0) {
        rem=dividend%10;
        dividend=dividend/10;
        sum=sum+rem;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Actually I'm wishing the result:
for n=1, result=1
for n=10, result=190
For explanation result contains 3 digits. and their sum 1+9+0 = 10 which is equal to n(10). Hope all are able to understand.

Please give me a better way for time saving of this problem. Cause my solution will take too much time. But I'm unable to understand others programming language. So, please explain this in C easily. Thanks for helping me in advanced.

I have find a solution but don't understand. Please allow me to understand the full program if you have enough time.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<queue>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
#define F first
#define S second
#define N 1100
#define mp make_pair
queue<pair<int, int> >Q;
short sumTrace[N][N], mulTrace[N][N];

void print(int sum, int mul)
{
    if (sumTrace[sum][mul] == 42)return;
    print(sum-sumTrace[sum][mul], mulTrace[sum][mul]);
    printf("%d",sumTrace[sum][mul]);
}
void solve(int n)
{
    Q.push(mp(0,0));
    sumTrace[0][0]=42; // any number greater than 9
    while (1)
    {
        int sum = Q.front().F;
        int mul = Q.front().S;
        if (sum == n && mul == 0) break;
        Q.pop();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            int nsum = sum+i;
            if (nsum > n)break;
            int nmul = (mul*10+i)%n;
            if (sumTrace[nsum][nmul] == -1)
            {
                Q.push(mp(nsum, nmul));
                sumTrace[nsum][nmul] = i;
                mulTrace[nsum][nmul] = mul;
            }
        }
    }
    print(n,0);
    while(!Q.empty())Q.pop();
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        memset(sumTrace, -1, sizeof sumTrace);
        solve(n);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quite likely for large `n`, you get an overflow from `dividend = n * i`. Sometimes `long long` is just not long enough.

Comment: Then How can I optimize this? May be string will help in this regard. But I'm unable to implement this thinking. If anyone can optimize this code I might have learned a new knowledge. So, Please try to optimize this code for me.

Comment: Using this approach for large values of `n` will require use of a Big Integer library which will be substantially faster than using strings.  Personally, I think there's probably a shortcut to solving this (which is I think what you're after) ... this problem has the ring of something from Project Euler.

Comment: And after a brief search http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123918/find-smallest-number-which-is-divisible-to-n-and-its-digits-sums-to-n and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851628/minimal-positive-number-divisible-to-n

Comment: And yet another resource: https://oeis.org/A002998

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One small possible optimization can be as follows:

You can use a bit of math here.

If there exists an `i` such that the sum of digits of `n*i` is `n`, then:

```
Say n*i = p + 10q + 100r + 1000s +... (where p, q, r, s are digits of n*i)
Then p + q + r + s ... = n.

Hence n * (i-1) = 9q + 99r + 999s +... (after subtracting n from both sides)
                = 9 * (q + 11r + 111s +... )
```

**Hence you notice that n*(i-1) shall always be a multiple of 9**.

So if n is originally not a multiple of 9, then you can skip many possible candidates by taking steps of 9 (`i += 9`) instead of 1 (`i++`).

You can think on these lines and you may come up with something better.

Comment: Thank you for your thinking. Obviously we will skip many steps so that time complexity will be decreased. But I can't implement this. Please optimize my code with your logic. and give a complete code so that the code runs in the compiler since I'm not an advanced programmer :(

Comment: stackoverflow isn't here to do the programming for you... just to help you on the way

Comment: Yah Chris Maes. That's better to figure out of a problem than a source code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? ;oP

```
m=n+1; while (summingDigit(m)!=n && m%n!=0) m++;
```

Or like you've done.

```
m=2*n; while (summingDigit(m)!=n) m+=n;
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? I can't understand. Please explain. Have you understood the requirement of this question/problem?

Comment: I'm just appropriating your code to understand the issue, and first I replace the infinite for _loop_ and the break condition by a _while_ loop.

Comment: The job of the function summingDigit(long long int dividend) is to calculate sum of digits of dividend. which dividend is also equal to n. For another example if input is 12 output will be 48. sum of digit of output 4+8 = 12 which is equal to n (12).

Comment: OK I understood. But my question is what if the n is 1000. The output will be a big big number!