# Is there a more effective implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Problem statement:

You are given two positive integers 
d
 and 
s
. Find minimal positive integer 
n
 which is divisible by 
d
 and has sum of digits equal to 
s
.

Input:

The first line contains two positive integers 
d
 and 
s
 (
1
≤
d
≤
500
,
1
≤
s
≤
5000
) separated by space.

Output:

Print the required number or -1 if it doesn't exist.

This my code:

```
d_and_s = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
counter_dracula = 0
while True:
    if counter_dracula%d_and_s[0] == 0 and sum(map(int, str(counter_dracula))) == d_and_s[1]:
        break
     counter_dracula += 1
     print(counter_dracula)
```

That's my implementation but clearly there must be a faster way.
For example if the Input is `13` and `50` the output is `699998`.
My code gives me the correct answer but takes a long time but even ultra longer in this sample testcase: Input is `61` and `2` and the output is `1000000000000000000000000000001`.

How can I implement them correctly using Python 3?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956688/minimal-positive-integer-divisible-by-n ?

Comment: Hi,

For one quite improvement, realize that the numbers divisible by d is d, 2*d, 3*d, 4*d , ...

So instead of incrementing the loop by 1 every time, you can increment with d

    def sum_digits3(n):
       r = 0
       while n:
           r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
       return r
       
    d, s = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    
    counter = 0
    
    while True:
        counter += d
        if sum(map(int, str(counter))) == s:
            break
    print(counter)

Comment: (sorry, cant post you the solution, with better format, question was closed)

Comment: Formatted here:
https://repl.it/repls/PriceyJovialEditor

Comment: I don't understand why @david-z closed the question, since the purported duplicate has the constraint that d == s (apart from being in C instead of python)

Comment: @WalterTross Ah, I missed that constraint in the other question. Nevertheless, I would like to have seen this question edited to mention the difference and say what mahir is still confused about after seeing the other question or why it doesn't help.

Comment: point is, @ChristianSloper answered in a comment (essentially the same answer I had in mind), and the OP was happy with that. Christian: you can go ahead and write a regular answer.

Comment: You could get a small improvement by assigning your input to `d, s` rather than `d_and_s`, so that you don't have to index into a list every time you want one of those values.

Comment: @WalterTross Thanks, I have moved my answer from repl.it to stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(yey, the question opened again :-) )

For one quite improvement, realize that the numbers divisible by d is d, 2*d, 3*d, 4*d , ...

So instead of incrementing the loop by 1 every time, you can increment with d

```
def sum_digits(n):
   r = 0
   while n:
       r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
   return r

d, s = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

counter = 0

while True:
    counter += d
    if sum_digits(counter) == s:
        break
print(counter)
```